# CircleCi can't hit database during Acceptance Testing

Tags: laravel, codeception, devops, circleci

I have two different types of tests in my project - Acceptance and Unit tests and the problem is that CircleCi cant hit the database during the acceptance tests, though the .env variables are the same.

Here is the .env file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=db_testing
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

In PHPUnit.xml I have this:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

And in my app:

```
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
```

All this setup works on my local machine, but on circleci it complains that it cant reach the database. According to their docs, I don't need to create the database

Answer (score 1):

> If you use MySQL or Postgres, you can use the `circle_test` database and the `ubuntu` user rather than creating the database yourself. No password is required for any database.

*Source: https://circleci.com/docs/manually/#databases*

```
jdbc:postgresql://ubuntu:@127.0.0.1:5432/circle_test
```

*Source: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#database*

To use database provided by CircleCI, I think need to use:

```
# .env
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=circle_test
DB_USERNAME=ubuntu
DB_PASSWORD=
```